# ASMX Web service is not getting all of the models sent

Tags: c#, .net, asmx

While creating new methods for ASMX service I imported using "XML as a class" tool two models.

They are similar except two root nodes.

```
<root1>
  <subroot1>
     <shared node>
     </shared node>
  </subroot1>
</root1>

<root2>
  <subroot2>
     <shared node>
     </shared node>
  </subroot2>
</root2>
```

I've moved all inner classes to another file and reused them.

I'm using SOAPUI tool to send requests.

And now strange thing happening:
When I'm sending the shared node received for one model, but for the second one not.

What could be wrong or how can I debug it?